# Accessibility - displaying a readonly version of a previous form input

Tags: html, accessibility

We are currently working improve the accessibilty of a previously written site.  We have a number of forms where the question/answers would be displayed like so:

```
<label for="answer1">Can you answer this question?</label>
<input type="text" id="answer1" />
```

(These can be fairly long forms, with a number of questions).  We then have a set of pages that display the data that you previously entered and saved for these forms (using the same layout, effectively just replacing the inputs with text, something like this:

```
<label>Can you answer this question?</label>
<span class="answer">No</span>
```

Now, when I assess this page from an accessibility point of view, I get a number of violations, due to the fact that the labels are not associated with a control.  I understand the point of this, and what I am wondering is what is the best way to layout these pages?  Logically (in my mind at least), this is still a label for the answer, however I understand that this is not what labels are intended for from the accessibility point of view.

Ideally I'd like to keep using the labels, as it stops a requirement for duplicate styling for whatever we use, however I think we may need to go through and change this to something like this:

```
<span class="question">Can you answer this question?</span>
<span class="answer">No</span>
```

I can't find any specific advice on this (or at least am unable to narrow a search enough to return a pertinent result).  I am looking for a way to lay this out in the most accessible fashion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd mark that up with a [definition list](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-dl-element):

> The dl element represents an association list consisting of zero or
>   more name-value groups (a description list). A name-value group
>   consists of one or more names (dt elements) followed by one or more
>   values (dd elements), ignoring any nodes other than dt and dd
>   elements. Within a single dl element, there should not be more than
>   one dt element for each name.
>
> Name-value groups may be terms and definitions, metadata topics and
>   values, questions and answers, or any other groups of name-value data.

```html
<h1>Your Answers</h1>
<dl>
  <dt>Can you answer this question?</dt>
  <dd class="answer">No</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: Interesting.  I note from a bit of quick digging that this element has been 'repurposed' in html 5 as a description list: http://html5doctor.com/the-dl-element/

Comment: Yes, also a very good one! @Paddy, if for some reason you don't want to stick with the `readonly` attribute I suggested in my answer, consider using a `dl`, it's also a very accessible solution.

Comment: @MenelionElensúlë - I'll need to assess both of these answers.  The readonly inputs seem sensible from the point of easy access, however I always find that a page full of 'readonly' inputs looks like it should have something to enter somewhere and should be 'submittable', while this page will not be.  That said, I need to go and look into both of these in more detail.

Comment: I think read only inputs could be possibly confusing to the users. It may not be clear why they can't change the answers.

Comment: Taking this as an answer.  The readonly inputs have their plus points as well, but I think this is a more sematic version of a page that cannot be edited at all.

Answer (score 3):

The best layout (at least, for the blind) would be just to add a `readonly` attribute to the `input`. I.E.:

```
<label for="answer1">Can you answer this question?</label>
<input type="text" id="answer1" value="No" readonly />
```

I consider this ideal because blind people still could navigate the page with their quick navigation keys and quickly jump to edit fields.

Answer (score -2):

You could look into some

```
<div class="thread">
  <p>Can you answer this question?</p>
  <p>No</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.thread p:first-child
{ 
  font-size:18px;
}
.thread p:last-child
{ 
  font-size:12px;
}
```

You could also use `.thread label{ };`

Not sure if this helps.

Comment: I'm not sure what the advantage of this is against what I have above?  I don't think I can use `.thread label` due to the accessibility issues.

Comment: You will be using less class="question" and class="answer"

Comment: Indeed that is true, but not sure how that helps from the accessibility point of view.

Comment: Paddy this is a poor solution. The point to showing the question and answer is their connection. This would not give any of this semantically. You can use ARIA to link them, or you  could use a built in element (which is stated early in the primer), a `dl`.